# Explorer view feature is not working, SharePoint 2007

Tags: explorer, 2007, webdav

The explorer view feature is not working on our SharePoint 2007 portal. When users try to view a SP list in explore view they are prompted with the following error:
"Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer."

In the past, this issue was caused by the following office update KB981715. But weeks after that update was retracted the error is occurring again. Thanks in advanced for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but webdav is disabled in Windows Vista and XP sp2 and explorer view uses webdav.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841215

Comment: Thanks. we restarted webdav on our servers and the feature started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Webclient service available and enabled on your client systems?

[More on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+explorer+view+not+working).

Comment: Web client is enabled and set to automatic at start up.